# Скрипт автопостинга Вконтакте

Tags: скрипт, php, вконтакте

Здрасте!

Есть такая задача. 
На сайте есть блок, информация которого меняется каждые n минут. 
Вот хотелось бы как то постить эту информацию в группу, а именно в Статус.

Кто подскажет скрипт или как это реализовать.

Comment: Как вариант отправка POST запросов с помощью CURL

Парсем нужный текст -> отправляем.

Это только предложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача сводится к следующей: с каким-то интервалом запускать скрипт, который бы постил определённую информацию вконтакт.

Начнём с конца: как запостить информацию в группу? По заданию не очень понятно куда и как именно, но в любом случае нужно начать с изучения [VK API](https://vk.com/dev/apiusage)

Дальше, "каждые N минут". Это просто, [man cronjob](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Но! Если задача интегрирована в сайт, "информация которого меняется каждые n минут" - никаких проблем, даже cron не нужен. Обратитесь к создателю сайта. Чтобы он передавал эту информацию в скрипт в процессе обновления.

Если нет - ваш скрипт, запускаемый по cron, должен брать информацию с сайта самостоятельно.

На этом, думаю, стоит остановиться, и узнать у вас: какая из подзадач вызывает вопросы?

Comment: Да в плане запуска скрипта и передачи информации в скрипт вопросов нет, а вот Вконтакте. Как постить именно в статус.

Comment: Вот те буковки, которые я выделил синим (VK API) - это ссылка. На неё нужно нажать. Немного ещё мозговых усилий - и вы попадёте [сюда][1]


  [3]: https://vk.com/dev/status.set